# How to get the querystring from a redirected uri

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am doing a webBrowser.navigate request by using a url which contains specific clientID and Password. After that it takes me to the page where again i need to fill some ID and Password. Then it will redirect me to a new page where i will get the authentication code in the query string.

Now i am having many problems.

```
    webBrowser1.Navigate(url)
        Dim elementLogin = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_identifier")
        If Not IsNothing(elementLogin) Then
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_identifier").SetAttribute("Value", user_email)
        End If
        Dim elementPassword = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_password")
        If Not IsNothing(elementLogin) Then
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_password").SetAttribute("Value", password)
        End If

        webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("login_btn").InvokeMember("click")
```

The  webBrowser1.Document has nothing so i pissed off. Can anyone there suggest me any other process to automate this...   Or might help me out if i am on the right track.  Thanks

Comment: the redirect will zap your query string. try using cookies instead

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit more..?

Comment: Because we are not on web so how i will use cookies.? we are using an API

Comment: Sorry I misunderstood. Are you following the redirect response?

Comment: Yes Its Oauth 2, type authorization. First i have to submit the authorization form. Then it asks for login and after that it will redirect me to new page in that new page url i will have the code.